# Laravel - SQL injection prevention with {{{ }}}

Tags: forms, laravel, input, sql-injection

I have some forms in my page made in Laravel. According to documentation, triple braces - {{{ }}} can escape the output. So when I use:

```
{{{ Form::text('name') }}}
```

can I be 100% sure that there is no possibility to insert SQL injection command into this form input?

Comment: No, tripple braces escapes potentially dangerous output. But your question shows lack of knowledge how web works, maybe you should start with some basic HTML to understand why framework can't prevent client from sending malicious data.

Comment: You missed something by a long, long mark. The triple braces aren't for SQL escaping. If you use laravel, SQL injection is not what you should worry about in the first place.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No you understood the `{{{` `}}}` wrong. They escape the **output**.
So if you do

```
{{{ Form::text('name') }}}
```

The result is this:

```
&lt;input name=&quot;test&quot; type=&quot;text&quot;&gt;
```

It still generates HTML code but it gets escaped so it's not interpreted as HTML but as plain text

### Preventing SQL injection

You have to prevent SQL injection when saving data to the DB. Normally you do that in your controller. If you use [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) or Laravels Query Builder you don't have to worry to much. It will take care of possible SQL injection points. Only if you execute raw SQL you have to pay attention.

From the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries):

> **Note:** The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding throughout to protect your application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to clean strings being passed as bindings.

Comment: Im using DB::table('table')->insert(['name' => $name]). This is raw querry you mean? Should I use {{{ $name }}}?

Comment: No. Raw queries would be uses `DB::raw()`, `whereRaw()` and `DB::statement()`. The pretty much always have "raw" in the method name